# DataTable fnFilter not working on IE9?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I filter a `jQuery.dataTable` dynamically calling the following method:

```
var table = $("#memberTable").dataTable({ bRetrieve: true });
var regex = "Facebook Twitter";
table.fnFilter(regex, 2, true);
```

I can build the regex argument to be passed to the `dataTable` as either `"(Facebook)|(Twitter)"`, or `Facebook|Twitter` and it still won't work on IE9. On Chrome and Firefox it works as expected. What could be the issue here? It'as as if IE didn't match any of the regexes?

Comment: Can you set up a test fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set the fourth parameter to false - it is the Datatables smartfilter and sometimes interferes with regex filtering:

```
table.fnFilter(regex, 2, true, false);
```